# navigator.serviceWorker.controller is always null

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I have the problem that after registering the serviceWorker the navigator.serviceWorker.controller is always null. I never do a force refresh and just refresh the page. I test it with Google Chrome 42.0.2311.152 m (32-Bit).

```
var currentServiceWorker = null;
navigator.serviceWorker.register(SERVICE_WORKER_URL).then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration { 
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    currentServiceWorker = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
  } else {
    currentServiceWorker = serviceWorkerRegistration.active;
  }
});
```

According to this:

> The controller read-only property of the ServiceWorkerContainer interface returns a ServiceWorker object if its state is activated (the same object returned by ServiceWorkerRegistration.active). This property returns null if the request is a force refresh (Shift + refresh) or if there is no active worker. ( Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller)

`navigator.serviceWorker.controller` should return the same object as `serviceWorkerRegistration.active`. But with `.active` I get the active worker, with `.controller` not.

Do you have any ideas for that situation?

Thank you,
Andi

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first thing I'd look at when debugging this is whether the current page you're on falls under the scope of the service worker. If your current page isn't under the scope, then it won't be controlled (but the service worker you registered can still be considered active).

You're calling `register(SERVICE_WORKER_URL)` which will, by default, use the directory that contains your service worker script as the scope. That's normally what you'd want, but you need to make sure that `SERVICE_WORKER_URL` refers to a script that's located at the root of your web site. That way, it will be able to control pages both at the same root level, or pages in directories underneath your web root. So if your service worker JavaScript file is currently under a `/scripts/` subdirectory or something like that, move it up to the root.

You can check the current scope of your service worker by visiting `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` and seeing what the scope associated with your registration is.

Comment: this is an epic pitfall, I believe it should be better documented - at least some clear error message would be nice. thanks!

Comment: @shabunc did the issue solved, i get null in controller.

Comment: This is such a bummer mainly while using webbpack and configuring output paths. Most of the setups configure to release output at "dist/js/chunk.js" and so sw registers at "http://sitename.com/js/" and fails to respond.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this in the service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    clients.claim();
    console.log('Ready!');
});
```

Comment: I had to do this and then use the method of Swapnil at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448233/use-navigator-serviceworker-controller-postmessage-it-will-alway-typeerror-c

Answer (score 2):

navigator.serviceWorker.register only register the serviceworker and activate it. but to get controller over the serviceworker you need to put your serviceworker in the public root folder so that all the pages will be in the scope and service worker will be attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

The clients.claim() answer did it for me, along with a controller changed listener :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("controllerchange", (evt) => {
    console.log("controller changed");
    this.controller = navigator.serviceWorker.controller;
});
```

Thanks Kushagra Gour

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "bypass for network" is not checked under developer tools > application > service worker. This will prevent your service worker controller from being set.