# Chrome Web App Install Banners Not Working

Tags: google-chrome, flask, manifest, service-worker

I'm following a very simple app install banner for Chrome 42+ using the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/app-install-banner/basic-banner), but it's not showing up. Service Worker is registered, server is running HTTPS, and the `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "appName",
    "short_name": "appName",
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-1x.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-2x.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-3x.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-4x.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    }]
}
```

Service Worker registered using following code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/service-worker.js', {
            scope: './static/'
        })
        .then(function (r) {
            console.log('Registered Service Worker');
        })
        .catch(function (whut) {
            console.error('Uh oh, there is a problem... ');
            console.error(whut);
        });
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
        outputElement.textContent = 'beforeinstallprompt Event fired';
    });
});
```

What am I missing? Not sure where to start. I also have enabled `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks` in Chrome settings.

One thing I should note is that I am using Flask so I wonder if the paths are not correct. I think the `start_url` could be a problem. Do I point to the `templates` folder in Flask? Because that's where the `index.html` file is. Tried it, but didn't work.

Comment: Well I had a typo. `display` was not in quotes in `manifest.json`. But still no luck.

Comment: While you're registering a service worker, are you sure that the service worker is actually controlling your page? Try leaving out the `scope` value, to use the default same-directory-as-the-SW behavior, and if your SW is served from `/static/`, then your pages should be as well. You can check whether the SW is or isn't controlling your page by entering `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.state` in the DevTools console.

Comment: Luckily I came across this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256390/navigator-serviceworker-controller-is-always-null and have resolved it. ServiceWorker state is `activated`. But the banner hasn't shown up yet.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Any idea what I can do next?

Comment: Quick check to make sure the `chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks` flag is working as intended: if you visit https://airhorner.com/, do you see the install banner right away?

Comment: @JeffPosnick Yes I do see the banners on other sites. I tested it on Google I/O 2015 website and the basic banner sample put out by Google on Github: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/app-install-banner/basic-banner. I should note that both `manifest.json` and `service-worker.js` are in the same directory.

Comment: Is your site deployed anywhere public that we can take a look at?

Comment: It's working now. Halfway through testing, I took `navigator.serviceWorker.register` outside of the `window.load` event. Placing it back inside it seems to have resolved it. Thanks for your help throughout. I learned things I didn't know.

Comment: I also think that the problem was that my directory was password protected. I have seen this after further testing. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I tried the sample here: 
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/basic-banner/index.html

It only works if the chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks flag is turned on.

If the flag is not set, even I load the URL after a few days the banner is not showing. Same for my implementation as well which is based on this sample.

Comment: If the Web App Install banner is not showing, try to clear the browser history. If you ever dismissed the banner, it will not prompt again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 3 elements on your manifest ( [MOZ Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) )

```
"related_applications": [{
        "platform": "web"
    }],
"related_applications": [],
"prefer_related_applications": false
```

Then your manifest result

```
{
    "name": "appName",
    "short_name": "appName",
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-1x.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-2x.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-3x.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    },{
        "src": "/static/img/app/launcher-icon-4x.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
    }],
    "related_applications": [{
            "platform": "web"
        }],
    "related_applications": [],
    "prefer_related_applications": false
}
```

If you have problems post your error and i can help you, i hope this help !

Comment: But `related_applications` is duplicated twice?