# use "navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage" it will alway "TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null"

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, messaging

I have the problem that after registering the service worker the `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` always is `null`.

I want to use `postMessage` to send a message to the service worker.
However, `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` always returns `null`,
and shows the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null`.

Sometimes I can use `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage`, but at other times `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` returns `null`,
I am not sure how to deal with this issue...

I have done some research, but I still cannot fix my issue...

Has anybody any ideas?

Thanks,
Terry

Here is the test page that I created.
https://terrylee7788.github.io/test_web_worker.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **navigator.serviceWorker.ready**

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
  // Let's see if you have a subscription already
  return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();
})
.then(function(subscription) {
  if (!subscription) {
    // You do not have subscription
  }
  // You have subscription.
  // Send data to service worker
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({'data': dataToServiceWorker});

})
```

Comment: That's unfortunately open to a race condition—the `.ready` promise can resolve before `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is set. See https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/799 which includes some workarounds.

Comment: The race condition that Jeff Posnick mentions means that conditioning on `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` is not a reliable solution. However, conditioning on his [`window._controlledPromise`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-sw/blob/fb5a32dd77a7ee9e4240a05e0d00a570b176fb25/test/controlled-promise.js) is reliable. Thanks @Jeff Posnick!